# Animating UIImageView over a background image

Tags: iphone

I have a UIImageView that I have resized to fit a small ball. The current background is black color. I want to set the background as some image and then move the ball on top of that image. I tried to use another UIImageView but the background takes over the ball image and the ball is not visible. Any ideas!

Comment: Do you have some code you could share, are are you doing everything in interface builder?

Comment: I am doing everything in the interface builder. I have a single nib file with 2 UIImageViews. One is small and the other one covers the whole screen. I want the smaller one on the front and the big one in the back which should serve as a background.

Comment: in IB, are you sure you have the small UIImageView in on top of the larger one? Try deleting the smaller UIImageView from IB and re-adding it on top of the larger one.

Comment: @j0BU1324 hahah that actually worked!! If you can post this as the answer then I can accept it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IB, are you sure you have the small UIImageView in on top of the larger one? Try deleting the smaller UIImageView from IB and re-adding it on top of the larger one. I noticed that it's hard to tell which UIView is on top in IB for some reason.

Posting as requested. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using interface build and just doing it programatically, much more control that way.

Comment: There is a certain simplicity to doing it programmatically, but there is also a very good argument to doing it through interface builder. Once you get it down, it can be a lot easier to work with your project, since the GUI is separate from the code. IB has come a long ways since it was first released!